# How to get an array of file names in valums

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Here is my js, and action

```
 public function postyAction()
 {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    // list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
    $allowedExtensions = array("jpeg","xlsx", "jpg", "gif", "doc", "docx", "xls", "odt", "pdf");
    // max file size in bytes
    $sizeLimit = 6 * 1024 * 1024;
    $f = '../dir/'; //dir to save files
    $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload($f);

    // to pass data through iframe you will need to encode all html tags
    echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

}  
function createUploader(){       
    var UploadedFileNames = [];
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            action: '../orders/posty',
            sizeLimit: 10000000, //10MB maximo
            debug:false,
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJson){
                var success = responseJson["success"];
                if(success == true){
                    var files = $(".qq-upload-file").toArray();
                    var UploadedFileNames = [];
                    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
                        UploadedFileNames.push( files[ i ].innerHTML );
                    }
                    $( "#filenem" ).val( UploadedFileNames.join( "#" ) );
                }
                //$("#filenem").val(fileName);
            }
        }); 

    }

    // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
    // don't wait for the window to load  
    window.onload = createUploader;
```

I wish to get an array of files onComplete(), so that i can insert them into db. my code gets the inner html of the file list but longer file names appear to be dotted hence cant get the real file name. eg . e"myverylongdocume..now.doc" instead of "myverylongdocumentnow.doc" for instance

Comment: How is this `handleUpload()` working.

Comment: it is a method in the valums qq.fileUploader class

Comment: Please refer to this.  [link](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader/blob/master/server/php.php)

Comment: The function `handleUpload()` is not returning filename.

Comment: `var files = $(".qq-upload-file").toArray();` am using that to get innerHtml of the list generated onComplete. Forming an array of files names. The problem is longer filenames are shortened with ... here is the js [link](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader/blob/master/client/fileuploader.js)                                                                                          They use a list  template to list the filenames successfully updated. search for fileTemplate: in the js